How to change the format that Java+BouncyCastle writes my private key?
I have a pkcs12 file that contains a public and private key pair that I created using openssl. My Java program reads in the pcks12 file and saves the public and private keys separately for use by the http daemon. Some keys, however, are causing problems.
When I create the key with RSA, everything works fine. The problem is with EC and specifically with Java and Bouncy Castle. I can extract the private key from the pkcs12 file on the command line and I get a file that starts '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----'. I can use the openssl ec command to read that file and the HTTP daemon accepts it too.
But the key that gets produced by Java starts '-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----'. The openssl ec command cannot read that and the HTTP daemon rejects it too.
I need to be able to export the private key so that it can be used by HTTP. I guess that means a key in the form that has '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----'. Or else, I need to be able to get the apache httpd daemon to accept the form that Java is outputting.
Detailed information below. Any help is greatly appreciated!
Here's how I created the private key:
openssl genpkey -algorithm EC -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:P-384 \
        -pkeyopt ec_param_enc:named_curve \
        -out "$KEY_DIR/$commonname.key" -pass pass:$PASSWORD


Here's how I extracted it from the PKCS12 file on the command line:
openssl pkcs12 -in rick5.p12 -nocerts -noenc -out good.key
And here's the gist of the Java code I use to write the private key (certfile is the PKCS12 file):
try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(certFile)) {
    
    KeyStore certs = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
    certs.load(in, certSecret_in.toCharArray());

} catch(Exception e){
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load server certificate", e);
}           

try (PEMWriter writer = new PEMWriter(new FileWriter(path))){
            
    Key key = certificate.getKey(alias, secret.toCharArray());
    writer.writeObject(key);
            
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not save private key", e);
}

Here's some other info that might be useful. In the output below, 'good.key' is the key I extracted from the pkcs12 file using the openssl command line. The 'bad.key' file is the one that Java produced.
root@rick5:lumeta# openssl ec -in good.key -noout -text
read EC key
Private-Key: (384 bit)
priv:
ac:76:0c:6a:08:9f:53:a1:7d:0e:a9:be:35:87:cc:
aa:a2:ce:05:86:2c:9d:41:df:fe:0e:d0:4d:07:a2:
bf:b2:6b:19:0b:09:3b:68:2a:b4:93:d6:c5:83:cf:
dd:c2:97
pub:
04:e9:77:06:a0:a4:72:47:e3:9a:1a:2b:ff:cc:54:
c7:85:a4:2b:2a:c3:ce:2c:8c:17:7e:18:8b:a1:e2:
d8:95:5f:22:84:eb:44:63:51:1e:f5:20:43:5e:4e:
87:32:30:2a:41:18:82:77:91:e0:a7:3a:89:24:26:
87:67:3d:a8:4d:0f:b4:27:65:21:40:86:c7:c5:32:
cc:e8:fd:7d:11:8d:bb:48:dc:f9:af:aa:4c:d7:cd:
7f:b6:94:5d:89:1c:e4
ASN1 OID: secp384r1
NIST CURVE: P-384

root@rick5:lumeta# openssl ec -in bad.key -noout -text
read EC key
Could not read private key from bad.key
402CCD163B7F0000:error:1608010C:STORE routines:ossl_store_handle_load_result:unsupported:crypto/store/store_result.c:151:
unable to load Key

root@rick5:lumeta#  openssl asn1parse -in good.key -strictpem
0:d=0  hl=3 l= 182 cons: SEQUENCE
3:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :00
6:d=1  hl=2 l=  16 cons: SEQUENCE
8:d=2  hl=2 l=   7 prim: OBJECT            :id-ecPublicKey
17:d=2  hl=2 l=   5 prim: OBJECT            :secp384r1
24:d=1  hl=3 l= 158 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:30819B0201010430AC760C6A089F53A17D0EA9BE3587CCAAA2CE05862C9D41DFFE0ED04D07A2BFB26B190B093B682AB493D6C583CFDDC297A16403620004E97706A0A47247E39A1A2BFFCC54C785A42B2AC3CE2C8C177E188BA1E2D8955F2284EB4463511EF520435E4E8732302A4118827791E0A73A89242687673DA84D0FB42765214086C7C532CCE8FD7D118DBB48DCF9AFAA4CD7CD7FB6945D891CE4

root@rick5:lumeta# openssl asn1parse -in bad.key -strictpem
0:d=0  hl=3 l= 155 cons: SEQUENCE
3:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :01
6:d=1  hl=2 l=  48 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:AC760C6A089F53A17D0EA9BE3587CCAAA2CE05862C9D41DFFE0ED04D07A2BFB26B190B093B682AB493D6C583CFDDC297
56:d=1  hl=2 l= 100 cons: cont [ 1 ]
58:d=2  hl=2 l=  98 prim: BIT STRING


Your code is not complete enough. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre].

First an aside: org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMWriter has been deprecated for about a decade and functionally replaced by org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter. However PEMWriter has been backpatched to use JcaMiscPEMGenerator the same way as JcaPEMWriter and thus actually works in your case, though this is not best practice.
Apache httpd CAN use either PKCS8-form privatekey (BEGIN/END [ENCRYPTED] PRIVATE KEY) or 'legacy' SEC1-form privatekey (BEGIN/END EC PRIVATE KEY, with or without 1421-style encryption), but the latter only if it is correctly structured, and the combination you used makes it incorrect. Specifically, the Oracle/OpenJDK provider (SunEC) encodes a privatekey as PKCS8 (standard for all JCA) which for EC specifies the curve in the AlgorithmIdentifier part and does not need to, and does not, re-specify it in the per-algorithm part. But Bouncy's MiscPEMGenerator (inherited by the Jca subclass) writes ONLY the per-algorithm=SEC1 part, probably because the Bouncy key implementation returns PKCS8 with the curve in BOTH places. Thus your code produces a SEC1-format key that doesn't identify the curve, which is unusable.
IF your PKCS12 was created with a 'friendly name' for the privatekey-and-cert, which you don't show or say, but you do use a variable alias rather than hardcoded "1" which leads me to hope this is the case (and you use apparently different passwords for the file and key, which implies you did NOT create it with OpenSSL) you can simply use the KeyStore type PKCS12 from Bouncy and your code works.
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12","BC");
    try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)){ ks.load(is,pass); }
    PrivateKey k1 = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, pass);
    PEMWriter p1 = new PEMWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("79269719.1")));
    p1.writeObject(k1); p1.close();

Alternatively, with any provider you can manually construct a SEC1 including the curve by essentially a reverse of what I did in Java Bouncy Castle generated ES256 key doesn't work with JWT.io (where the need was to remove it):
    // given PrivateKey k1 containing an Oracle/OpenJDK(SunEC) key
    // manually insert params to SEC1
    PrivateKeyInfo p8 = PrivateKeyInfo.getInstance(k1.getEncoded());
    // ECPrivateKey is org.bouncycastle.asn1.sec not java.security.interfaces or org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces
    ECPrivateKey sec = ECPrivateKey.getInstance(p8.parsePrivateKey());
    // can retain sec.getPublicKey() in second argument if desired, but OpenSSL/Apache doesn't need it
    sec = new ECPrivateKey(256,sec.getKey(),null,p8.getPrivateKeyAlgorithm().getParameters());
    p1 = new PEMWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("79269719.2")));
    p1.writeObject(new PemObject("EC PRIVATE KEY", sec.getEncoded())); p1.close();

On the other hand, if you want you can use the more standard/portable PKCS8 either of two ways:
    // or generate PKCS8
    p1 = new PEMWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("79269719.3")));
    p1.writeObject(new JcaPKCS8Generator(k1,null)); p1.close();
    // or manually
    p1 = new PEMWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("79269719.4")));
    p1.writeObject(new PemObject("PRIVATE KEY", k1.getEncoded())); p1.close();

The former, JcaPKCS8Generator, can also produce encrypted PKCS8 by using the second argument to the ctor, but getting a password into Apache to decrypt a privatekey is often a pain.

Thanks for the detailed answer!
This is old code that I'm maintaining, so that's why the old PEMWriter. And I am using the same password for file and key, it's just my code snippets came from different methods.
Unfortunately, the stumbling block here is that I cannot cast the private key that Keystore.getKey(...) returns into a PrivateKey.

Error message:
Dec 11 2024 08:30:29.209 [A 127224355-24] ERROR (CertificateManagerImpl      ) - ClassCastException: class sun.security.ec.ECPrivateKeyImpl cannot be cast to class org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces.ECPrivateKey (sun.security.ec.ECPrivateKeyImpl is in module jdk.crypto.ec of loader 'platform'; org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces.ECPrivateKey is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @338fc1d8)

Fixed! The trick to using @dave_tompson_085's excellent answer was to get the PrivateKeyEntry in order to get the full private key. In addition, I changed all instances of PEMWriter to JcaPEMWriter.
With that I used the following code to successfully write the private key:
KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam =
        new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(secret.toCharArray());
KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry =
        (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) certificate.getEntry(alias, protParam);
PrivateKey key = pkEntry.getPrivateKey();
writer.writeObject(new JcaPKCS8Generator(key, null));

